# How many solutions does $\left(a-x\right)\left(b-x\right)=\left(1-ax\right)\left(1-bx\right)$ have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

I got this question from a friend of mine, and my solution that I gave to my friend was wrong. He did not explain why it was wrong, he only gave the answer.

The question is:

> How many solutions does following problem have:
> $$\left(a-x\right)\left(b-x\right)=\left(1-ax\right)\left(1-bx\right)$$

My solution (that was wrong) is this;

Step 1 - write the equation

$\left(a-x\right)\left(b-x\right)=\left(1-ax\right)\left(1-bx\right)$

Step 2 - simplify the left side of the equation

$\left(a-x\right)\left(b-x\right)=ab-ax-bx+x^2=ab-x\left(a+b\right)+x^2$

Step 3 - simplify the right side of the equation

$\left(1-ax\right)\left(1-bx\right)=1-bx-ax+abx^2=1-x\left(a+b\right)+abx^2$

Step 4 - simplify the equation even more by putting the right side to the left side

$\left(ab-1\right)+\left(1-ab\right)x^2=0$

Step 5 - divide the equation by (1-ab)

$\frac{\left(ab-1\right)}{\left(1-ab\right)}+x^2=0$

Step 6 - solve for x^2

$x^2=\frac{\left(ab-1\right)}{\left(ab-1\right)}=1\:\Longrightarrow x=\pm 1$

So my answer based on this calculation would be that there are to answers for x. But this is still wrong? Why is this wrong?

Here is the real answer:

> \begin{align} Number\:of\:solutions\:can't\:be\:decided. \end{align}

Comment: What if $ab-1=0$? Then you can't divide by $ab-1$ as in step 5. So the number of solutions depends on the value of $ab-1$ (whether is 0 or not)

Comment: I think this answers the question because I can't think of anything else.

Comment: BTW: You can get through the problem more quickly by simply moving everything to one side of the equation and factoring to give $$(1-ab)(x-1)(x+1)=0$$ Then, clearly, if $ab\neq 1$ there are two solutions, $x=\pm1$; otherwise, any value of $x$ works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Division $n/d$ as an operation is only defined when $d \neq 0$.  So you have two possibilities when you reach step 4.  Either $1 - ab = 0$ or $1 - ab \neq 0$.  If $1-ab \neq 0$, then the rest of your solution works, so you have 2 solutions.  If $1-ab = 0$, then the equation from step 4 becomes $0 = 0$, which is true regardless of the value of $x$; in that case, you get one solution for each real number (so infinitely many)!